# feeding dynamic variable names into $_POST

Tags: php

```
isset($_POST['"$daysofweek[i]"'])
```

I tried different variations but i can't get it to detect. I have an array with all the days of the week and I want to check every POST variable.

It's probably really simple, but im stuck.

Thanks

Comment: What does `$_POST` actually have in it? What does `$daysofweek` have in it? Where does `i` come from and shouldn't it be `$i`? You do know what single quoted strings do not interpolate, so that code is looking for `<input name="&quot;$daysofweek[i]&quot;">` (with no PHP operating at all on that HTML fragment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$i` is also a PHP variable (in a loop maybe):

```
isset($_POST[$daysofweek[$i]])
```

Comment: @Adam: I just happen to be about to head the other direction (PHP -> ActionScript)

Answer (score 0):

```
isset($_POST[$daysofweek[$i]])
```